# How do I know which hosting type a website is using?

Tags: web-server, web-hosting

I'd love to know if there is anything I can do to know if a website is on a shared hosting, VPS or even a dedicated hosting?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to know this for certain; even if other sites have the same IP address, it could be that there is a reverse proxy in front of them, doing load balancing across various backend servers.

Answer (score 2):

Really not sure there are any technical methods that wouldn't rely entirely on the site owners exposing this information to all, which would be pointless. The best way would be simply ask.

Answer (score 0):

There is no technical method or trick to know hosting service type of any website. You can ask to the site owner if really want to know about it, and i don't think any site owner have any issue in exposing this fact. Just contact them on contact info mentioned on their contact page, and tell him the motto **Why you want to know ?**

Answer (score 0):

A webSITE may be using all of those - and other things too.

But a webSERVER can only be one of them.

Only the website owner and (if applicable) the hosting provider can sensibly by privy to this information.

If you are the website owner and you're not confident that the hosting company is giving you the service they are billing you for, then it's quite easy to discriminate between shared hosting and the other types - you will only have full OS admin rights (i.e. a root login on POSIX systems) on the non-shared hosting.

As to differentiating between a virtual and dedicated server - you'll need to dredge through the device drivers to work that one out.